# popupwindow not working with setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout

## **Solution**


Thanks to a clue in codeMagic's answer, the solution to the problem was to set the width and height using the [setWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setWidth%28int%29) and [setHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setHeight%28int%29) methods

---

## **Question**


I am trying to display a PopupWindow in Android using the following code but it doesn't seem to be working

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        PopupWindow test = new PopupWindow();
        test.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, false));
        test.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_container), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
    ....
}
```

Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
What I expect a popup windows to show contain my layout in R.id.test but when i execute the code above, nothing happens. No error or whatsoever

EDIT2:
Added some context to the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use a `PopupWindow` for what I'm working on now. Mine is in a `ListView` so it may be a little different but I had to change a couple things to see it. Here are a few things I would suggest to look at because I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

1. Inflate your `View` first and make sure it doesn't return `null`
2. Use a different constructor ( I used `new PopupWindow(holder.textNotes, 500, 500, true);`
       - Replace `holder.textNotes` with your inflated `View` and the sizes with something suitable for the screen you are working on. 
   **Note** I used this constructor so I could make it focusable for an `EditText`

3 .I gave my `View` a background color so I could make sure it was showing

There are several different constructors you can use when creating an instance of `PopupWindow` which you can find [here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). The one I have used above allows you to set the `height` and `width` of the window. This prevents the need for the calls, `setHeight()` and `setWidth()` as pointed out by vidhu in the comments.

Comment: I edited my question. Also i do have to inflate to pass in a **view object**. R.layout.test is simply an **integer**

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was thinking it had a method that took a `resId` like `Activity` does. I will look at it some more. Can you show how your are calling this code or have you debugged to make sure it is being called correctly?

Comment: hi, i added some more edits. I am basically calling this code in the onCreate event of my main activity. and yes I debugged this, and it executes the code. There is something definitely wring with the way Im creating or calling the popup but I cant seem to figure out why

Comment: Is `R.id.main_container` a `View` inside `activity_main`? If so, I would put a breakpoint at the next line after `setContentView()` and make sure that `inflater.inflate(R.layout.test` doesn't return `null`

Comment: I updated my answer with some things I ran across in case they can help you find your issue

Comment: Ahh yes, that's it! The constructor you mention is the key. If you look closely, you give it a width and height in the constructor. Where as in my code i need to called the **SetWidth** and **SetHeight** methods. You can edit your ans to include this since someone else might stumble across this post

Comment: I will edit it soon to make it more clear. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

You should call method [update](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#update%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
to display your popup

Comment: That should only be needed if it is already showing and you want to update the content

Comment: according to your link it says "Updates the position and the dimension of the popup window" but the thing is, it's not showing up in the first place

Comment: Here the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android)
This script don't work?

`PopupWindow test = new PopupWindow();
test.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, false));
test.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_container), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
test.udpate(0,0,300,100);`

Comment: @cooperok I added the solution in my question. The reason the update() method works is because it also sets the width and height of the popupWindow. So the solution was to set the width and height of the windows by calling the setWith() and setHeight() method.